# Enumerable.Empty<T>() is good option to use instead of null check in foreach loop or not (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Consider we have classes:

```
public class Notes
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public List<Notes> ImportantNotes { get; set; }
}
```

Then to handle the case where we might getting `ImportantNotes` null, we will do something like this:

```
if (config.ImportantNotes != null)
{
    foreach(var note in config.ImportantNotes)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I have used this pattern a lot till now in my code but recently I came to know about Linq's Enumerable.Empty() method. Which I can use like this:

```
foreach(var note in config.ImportantNotes ?? Enumerable.Empty<ImportantNotes>())
{
    ....
}
```

I have checked, and it does work well in actual code, but I'm not sure if is it good to use or not. So, is it better to use this for handling null checks or not? If not then Why Not?

Comment: I would suggest that it's a non-issue because your design is flawed from the outset. You should replace `public List<Notes> ImportantNotes { get; set; }` with `public List<Notes> ImportantNotes { get; } = new();`. Collection properties should pretty much always be read-only so consuming code cannot replace the existing collection with an entire new one. The property will thus never be `null` and your question becomes moot.

Comment: Yes, but this will make it read-only can we add, or update items to it without set?

Comment: Yes, of course. the Readonly here only refers to the reference of the list itself - so you can't do `config.ImportantNotes = new List<Notes>()` but you can do `config.ImportantNotes.Add()` or `config.ImportantNotes.Remove()` or whatever.

Comment: Of course you can. If you want to add an item to the list, do you need to set the property, i.e. assign a different `List` object to the property? Of course you don't. You need to get the existing `List` object from the property and then call `Add` on that object. Think of basically any collection property throughout the .NET base class library and check whether it has a setter and it won't. They are pretty much all read-only.

Answer (score 5):

When using collection properties like `List<T>` you should design your class to either manage only one list that can't be replaced or make the collection itself readonly, but the property settable. So consider one of these:

```
public class Configuration
{
    // Everyone can add or remove items, but the list itself can't be replaced.
    public List<Notes> ImportantNotes { get; } = new();
}

public class Configuration
{
    // Everyone can replace the list, but items can't be changed.
    // Assume only good citizens and don't check for anyone setting this to null.
    public IReadOnlyList<Notes> ImportantNotes { get; set; } = Array.Empty<Notes>();
}

public class Configuration
{
    private readonly List<Notes> _ImportantNotes = new();

    // Everyone can read this list, but the configuration only can add or remove items.
    public IReadOnlyList<Notes> ImportantNotes { get => _ImportantNotes }
}

public class Configuration
{
    private IReadOnlyList<Notes> _ImportantNotes = Array.Empty<Notes>();

    // Everyone can replace the list, but items can't be changed.
    // Assume also bad citizens and check for anyone setting this to null.
    public IReadOnlyList<Notes> ImportantNotes
    {
        get => _ImportantNotes;
        set => _ImportantNotes = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that all of these approaches are valid. There is no better or worse. They all have their advantages and disadvantages and it depends on the use-case which best fit to your given problem. The only rule I always follow is that a collection should never be `null`. It can contain zero elements, but it itself is never `null`. This should be followed by properties and also methods which return collections (doesn't matter if the *collection* is `List<T>`, `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IReadOnlySet<T>` or any other similar type or interface).